# CORS not allowed origins in .net

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, cors

I need to check if I can catch requests of everything other than https://xxxx.com that is blocked by cors and trying to connect to the api.

This is how i am using CORS:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "https://xxxx.com", headers: "*", methods: "GET,POST")]
public class tesingController : ApiController
{       
    _testService = testService;
    _fileProvider = new FileProvider();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by: "catch", I'm sure you can dig in the Application_BeginRequest or Application_EndRequest to see the origin and act in consequence, but you might want to "catch" that in a controller/filter/handler?

Answer (score 0):

in case of webapi 2.1
be sure to have cors enabled

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "Your Verbs")); //// HttpConfiguration
```

but ensure, that your using it before

```
// if your using owin
// appBuilder.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

appBuilder.UseWebApi(configuration);
configuration.EnsureInitialized();
```